# Computational Complexity of a Matrix Multiplication

Tags: time-complexity, multiplication, matrix

I am computing a matrix multiplication with inverse operation $AB^{-1}C$ $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times o}$. So the inverse operation takes $O(n^3)$. Multiplying $B^{-1}C$ takes $O(n^2o)$ and multiplying $A(B^{-1}C)$ takes $O(mno)$. So the overall time complexity is $O(n^3 + n^2o + mno)$. Kindly correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.

Comment: Here is a hint. You are correct if you are computing $A(B^{-1}C)$.

Comment: Thanks Apass. I agree I would get different time complexity if I did $(AB^{-1})C$.